# Wrapping Logstash _source with Json

Tags: json, logstash

I am trying to wrap the output from Logstash in additional JSON. For example, here is some sample output from a syslog -

```
{
  "_index": "----",
  "_type": "----",
  "_id": "----",
  "_score": ----,
  "_source": {
    "message": "----",
    "@version": "----",
    "@timestamp": "----",
    "host": "----",
    "priority": ----,
    "timestamp": "----",
    "logsource": "----",
    "program": "----",
    "severity": ----,
    "facility": ----,
    "facility_label": ----,
    "severity_label": ----"
  },
}
```

What I want, is to wrap that, so what gets output is -

```
{
  "event": {
      "payload": { 
          ** EVERYTHING FROM ABOVE** 
      }  
  }
}
```

So wrapping the message above in "event" and "payload". I actually only care about the content in _source, so a solution for either would be phenomenal.

Edit#1: To add more specifics - I am trying to do this through the logstash filter. I am aware of how to add/rename/delete a field, but I am not sure how to take the current content and wrap it using a filter. If there was a way to access all of the information in "_source", that would be a great start.

Comment: Hm? I thought this was a very valid and specific question. I have investigated solving this problem, but came up with nothing. So, I was hoping to pull on the expertise of people  who may have done this before. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: You can use `mutate/add_field` in order to "move" the `_source` fields into another part of your event. `add_field => {"[event][payload][priority]" => "[_source][priority]"}`

Comment: The problem with *"I was hoping to pull on the expertise of people who may have done this before."* is that it is cheap. The only skill it requires is sitting there and waiting until someone does what was supposed to be your job. This site exists to help people learn, implementing solutions to their problems merely is the *side effect*, not the main goal.  In your post, it's the main goal. You describe your task and sit tight waiting until someone else does it for you. Otherwise your post would contain your attempts so far and some reasoning about them. That's the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, Val! Thank was exactly what I was looking for. I did not realize I would be able to access the tag in that way. Tomalak, I still don't see it, my friend. I'm not asking for someone to write code for me. I had a fairly simple problem that should have a fairly simple solution (as Val illustrated) - I was just not sure how to do it. I never asked for the solution to be implemented, and he didn't. He passed his expertise on, which I will now implement. Have a good one, and thanks again Val!